# Auto parsing and formatting JSON property names

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I use a script to auto populate form. When user selects an option from dropdown, it makes AJAX request to an external file (which returns data from database using `json_encode`) and forms gets auto-filled.

Here's the code:

```
function myrequest(e) {
    var name = $('#username').val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "autofill.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            username: name
        },
        success: function(responseObject) {
            $('#posts').val(responseObject.posts);
            $('#joindate').val(responseObject.joindate);
        }
    });
}
```

As you see, when dropdown with ID `username` is changed, AJAX call is made, and form fields with IDs `posts` and `joindate` are auto-filled.

However, I want to use the same function for more forms which will have fields with different IDs to be auto-filled (and JSON will return other data, of course). Is there any way to modify this function, so I don't need to write a separate line (like `$('#posts').val(responseObject.posts);`) for each JSON value to be parsed.

In other words, the function should auto parse returned JSON data and if there's a field with a specific ID, it should be auto filled. So if JSON returns data like `{"abc123":"666","some_other_field":"2017-03-06"}`, function should find and prefill fields with IDs `abc123` and `some_other_field` accordingly.

Comment: Most of these kinds of problems can be solved with bracket notation. For example, responseObject [ someVariable ] = someOtherValue. Assuming someVariable = 'abc123', this will fill in responseObject.abc123 with someOtherValue (and if the property doesn't exist on the object, it will create it). So, you could just pass in an array of property names and values depending on how you want the object set up, and there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like this could work:

```
function myrequest(e) {
    var name = $('#username').val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "autofill.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            username: name
        },
        success: function(responseObject) {
            for (var prop in responseObject) {
                if (responseObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    $('#' + prop).val(responseObject[prop]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No problem! Please mark as answer if this answered your question.